# How to avoid passing dispatch as a prop to component that requires it, but receives dispatch via connect()?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a component that has dispatch connected to it:

```
function MyComponent(props: Props) {
...
}

interface Props {
    dispatch: any
}

export default connect()(MyComponent)
```

Rendering this component in another component will throw an error if dispatch is not provided as a prop:

`Property 'dipsatch' is missing in type '{}'`

Do I have to connect the parent component and pass dispatch as a prop, or is there a better way around this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not provide a second argument to connect your component will automatically be given a dispatch prop.

See here: https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#mapdispatchtoprops-object--dispatch-ownprops--object

I would double check that everything is wired up correctly, this type of error likely means something isn’t being connected properly.

Comment: Agh, I misspelled dispatch in my props interface! Thanks